# How do I get apache to serve publicly in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, http, apache-http-server

I've gotten "Web sharing" back easily enough via https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083 and other articles.  But it only shares on my own system with localhost.  How can I get it back to where it will serve my Sites publicly to other machines?

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of questions.

I'm assuming you are doing this at home. At the moment if you point your web browser at `http://localhost` on the machine running Apache you get a page that says `It Works!`

When you say

> it only shares on my own system with localhost

then a machine on the same network when pointed at `http://192.168.1.9/` (or whatever your IP address is) does not see the same page.

What does it see?

As a first step, in `System Preferences` go to `Security & Privacy` and check that the firewall is off.

Second step is to check the Apache logs at `/var/log/apache2` To make sure that you have the correct log files look and see if a good page access from your machine is in `access_log` and then see if anything gets logged into `error_log` when you try from another machine.

Next, we need to look for a `Listen` command in the Apache config file. In `/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf` there should be a line `Listen 80`

Finally, check for another `Listen` command that might override that. At the command line go to `/etc/apache2` and then `grep "Listen" */*` will list all lines in any of the config files that might do that.

If a machine on the same net sees the right page and you want the web server seen by the outside world then that's a question of configuring your router properly.

Comment: "What does it see?" In FF I get "The connection has timed out.  The server at <the dns name of my machine> is taking too long to respond."  Firewall is off

Comment: I've added some more ideas of places to look for information. I suspect that there is a "Listen" line that is restricted to '127.0.0.1' somewhere.